# Como manipular o DOM através de uma extensão?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão

Estou começando a trabalhar com extensões no Google Chrome e depois de algum tempo lendo tutoriais eu até agora não consegui acessar nada no DOM da página. Estou precisando modificar o CSS da página ou executar algum script dentro da mesma. Alguém poderia me passar algum exemplo?

Procuro algo desse tipo:

**index.html**

```html
<html>
   <head>
       <title>teste de extensão</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button id="btn1" onclick="fundoAzul()">fundo azul</button>
      <br>
      <button id="btn1" onclick="fundoVermelho()">fundo vermelho</button>
      <script>
          function fundoAzul(){
            document.querySelector('body').style.background = 'blue';
          };
          function fundoVermelho(){
            document.querySelector('body').style.background = 'red';
          };
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Nos tutoriais que eu vi, um deles me mostrou como fazer um `alert` (não lembro qual agora) mas o meu `alert` era executado dentro da extensão e não na página atual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Veja um exemplo básico:

`manifest.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Exemplo StackOverflow",
    "description": "Demonstração de como utilizar content_script",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://pt.stackoverflow.com"],
        "js": ["script.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

`script.js`:

```
document.body.style.background = 'red';
```

Comment: cara, fantástico isso, realmente agora funcionou! agora posso criar minha extensão sem medo de ser feliz rsrs, obrigado